# loading content of the web page using jquery.load() method

Tags: javascript, asp.net

hello i am using single page application for one project in asp.net in which my header and leftside bar page is aspx page which i load using ajax method.in leftside bar there are different links and when i click the content of web page is display in div tag set for content as my header and leftside bar should not be reload again and again.Now the porblem i am facing is the i have a AssignTender.aspx which i call from the leftside bar link and for that i have use  .the page is loading perfectly.I have used  and when i click on button it redirect to AssignTender.aspx page.That should not be happen as assignTender.aspx page only should load in Content part of Index.aspx page.

```
Can any one has solution for this...
here is my script

  $(function () {
            callAjax("Login.aspx?FromWhere=LoggedInUserID","GET", null);
            $("#Header").load("Header.aspx");
            $("#leftDrawerHeader").load("LeftDrawer.aspx");
            $("#bodyContent").load("Dashboard.aspx");          
        });

function getBodyHtml(pageName){
    $("#bodyContent").empty();
    alert(pageName);
    $("#bodyContent").load(pageName);
}

    leftside aspx page code
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#TopHeader").load("Header.aspx");
        });
    </script>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
          <div id="TopHeader"></div>
            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">                    
                        <li id="AssignTender_link">
                            <a href="#" onclick='getBodyHtml("AssignTender.aspx")'  class="active">AssignTender</a>
                        </li> 
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

AssignTender.aspx page

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
         <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2 class="page-header">Assign Tender</h2>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                 <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <form runat="server" id="form1">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblcount" runat="server" Text="TenderCount" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                   &nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblcounts" runat="server" Text="5"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Classification Users" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Width="155px">
                                            <asp:ListItem>abcd</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>xyz</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:ListBox>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>

                                     <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Assign"  ID="btnassign" OnClick="btnassign_Click"  /> 
                                    <!-- <input type="button" id="Btnassign"  value="Assign" class="btn btn-primary" />-->

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table> 
                       </div>
                    </form>

                     </div>
                 </div>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where's the rest of the code?

Comment: @Matthias which part of code do you want

Comment: the code you refer to in your text, code with the div and all that (assigntender.aspx for example). It would also be helpful to see which file you have shown code from already

Comment: please edit your question and put the code there

Comment: @Matthias i have post the code

Comment: hmm the whole question itself is also pretty unclear to me. Maybe you can clarify. What exactly do you want to happen and what is it that happens now? (might also want to fix the formatting in your question to be more aesthetically pleasing)
For example which button are you referring to in your text? and what is the `content` part? and what is the `index.aspx` page?